# ASP.NET MVC - Potentially dangerous request.Form value '<' and/or '>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, encoding

I get this error when I type in `'<test>'` on a textarea, so I assume the characters `'<'` and `'>'` are causing it.

As I'm looking for ways to fix it, I've found that the great majority of people recommends adding this to the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

or adding this to my action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

But I'm afraid that doing so would leave me open to malicious input like sql injection and the like, so I'd like to know whats the safer way to fix this issue.

PS: I'm using textareafor (although I'm not sure it makes any difference).

Comment: You want to put in textarea field some data which contains dangerous symbols and then read it?

Comment: How about decorating your model with [`AllowHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Well, I haven't thought about the reading part until now, I think I could ignore that character if thats the case... I could create a jquery validation to stop the user from typing those characters, but I wouldnt be sure what to allow and what to restrict

Comment: Well, you'll have to choose, either have the built-in validation and sanitizing or do it yourself. You can't have asp.net validate the request but let it through when it's not an attach. There's no way it can detect the difference

Comment: @Brad Christie, Could you tell me what sort of side effects that could cause me? like, would a javascript alert come out if I typed in 'alert('a')' on an input with allowhtml?

Comment: @BrenoSarkis: potentially, yes. it doesn't make it safe, just acceptable.

Comment: @Kenneth, So by your judgment, the safer thing to do would be to validate the input on the client?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `[AllowHtml]` attribute to your property in the view model.

The SQL injection attack can be made regardless of the ValidateModel. The danger is in the XSS attacks. For preventing XSS attacks you can encode your HTML.

Comment: I've used SQL Injection just as an example of bad things that could happend, it's not like I'm trying to protect myself from that only

Comment: The only danger is in the XSS attacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting 
But MVC automatically encodes your output unless you select Html.Raw to the output